# Does `address.transfer` forward all gas (suceptible to re-entrancy)?

Tags: solidity, reentrant-attacks, address.transfer

From the Solidity [documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security-considerations.html#sending-and-receiving-ether) I do not understand if the recently introduced `address.transfer` forwards all gas to the target contract or just gives a minimal gas stipend. I.e.: Would it facilitate re-entrancy attacks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I setup a minimal test example that you can find on https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07d4714c27dbf1af0e5cb16c9f833353

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Test {
    Receiver myR;

    function setReceiver (address a) {
        myR = Receiver(a);
    }

    function callR() {
        myR.call(this.balance);
    }

    function sendCash() payable {
    }

}

contract Receiver {
    uint public numCalled;

    function () payable {
        numCalled++;
    }
}
```

Which works well and after setting the `Receiver` contract address in `Test` via `setReceiver` and upon calling `callR` the `numCalled` in `Receiver` increases. When replacing the `myR.call` by `myR.transfer` I get an exception. Single-stepping with the Remix debugger into this shows that `myR.transfer` only got a gas stipend of 2300 gas which is not sufficient to set a storage variable or recursive calls.

Hence I conclude that `transfer` is save and does not allow for re-entrancy attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and find out?

```
contract TestInterface {
  function reentrance(address dest);
}

contract Test is TestInterface {
  uint8 private _depth = 0;

  // make it payable
  function () payable {}

  event Entered(uint8 depth);

  function reentrance(address dest) {
    if (_depth > 2) {
      // yep
      throw;
    }
    Entered(_depth);
    _depth++;
    dest.transfer(this.balance);
  }
}

contract Destination {
  function () payable {
    TestInterface sender = TestInterface(msg.sender);
    // send it back so we can do it again.
    msg.sender.send(this.balance);
    sender.reentrance(this);
  }
}

// deploy Test
// send Test some ETH
// Deploy Destination
// call Test.reentrance with Destination's address
// Watch for events from Test
```